# Creating a report with an expiration date less than 2 weeks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, date, momentjs

I am currently creating a report that will only return customers with an expiration date less than two weeks away.

My current report is returning all of the customers.

```
/* @format - for Prettier */
import React from 'react'
import _ from 'lodash'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { Table, Button, Glyphicon } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { Customers as CustomersActions } from '../../actions'
import { DeniedWrapper } from '../../styled'
import moment from 'moment'
import ReactExport from 'react-data-export'

const ExcelFile = ReactExport.ExcelFile
const ExcelSheet = ReactExport.ExcelFile.ExcelSheet
const ExcelColumn = ReactExport.ExcelFile.ExcelColumn

const CustomersWrapper = styled.div`
  width: 80vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
`

const ToolButton = styled(Button)`
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
`

const AddGlyph = styled(Glyphicon)`
  margin-right: 5px;
`

const Header = styled.div`
  margintop: '10px';
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
`
const ExportButton = (
  <ToolButton bsStyle="primary">
    <AddGlyph glyph="export" />
    Export to Excel
  </ToolButton>
)

class ExpiringContracts extends React.Component {
  state = {
    show: false,
    customer: null,
    searchText: '',
    startDate: moment().format('L'),
    endDate: moment().add(14, 'days').calendar()
  }

  componentDidMount(next) {
    this.props.getCustomers()
  }

  render() {
    if (this.props.authorized) {
      return (
        <CustomersWrapper>
          <Header>
            <ExcelFile element={ExportButton} filename={moment().format('L')}>
              <ExcelSheet data={this.props.customers} name="Expiring Contracts">
                <ExcelColumn label="Customer" value="name" />
                <ExcelColumn label="Expiration Date" value="expirationDate" />
              </ExcelSheet>
            </ExcelFile>
          </Header>

          <Table hover bordered>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Customer</th>
                <th>Expiration Date</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {_.map(this.props.customers, (customer) => {
                if (
                  (customer.expirationMonth,
                  customer.expirationDay,
                  customer.expirationYear >= this.state.endDate)
                ) {
                  return (
                    <tr
                      key={customer.uid}
                      onClick={() => this.props.setCustomer(customer.uid)}
                    >
                      <td>{customer.name}</td>
                      <td>
                        {customer.expirationMonth} / {customer.expirationDay} /{' '}
                        {customer.expirationYear}{' '}
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  )
                }
              })}
            </tbody>
          </Table>
        </CustomersWrapper>
      )
    } else {
      return <DeniedWrapper> Access Denied </DeniedWrapper>
    }
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  customers: state.customers,
  authorized: state.user.pages.customers
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  setCustomer: (uid) => dispatch(CustomersActions.setCustomer(uid)),
  getCustomers: () => dispatch(CustomersActions.getCustomers())
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ExpiringContracts)
```

I am using Moment.js as the endDate as a reference to the two weeks from today.

customer.expirationMonth, customer.expirationDay, customer.expirationYear return 2/24/21 format as reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [moment.diff](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/).

Here is an example:

```js
function expiryWithin(inputDates, ms) {
  const now = new Date()
  return inputDates.filter((inputDate) => moment(inputDate).diff(now) <= ms)
}

const _msTwoWeeks = 2 * 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
const _inputDates = [
  '2021-02-27T00:00:00.000Z',
  '2021-03-06T00:00:00.000Z',
  '2021-03-13T00:00:00.000Z',
  '2021-03-20T00:00:00.000Z',
  '2021-03-27T00:00:00.000Z',
]
console.log(expiryWithin(_inputDates, _msTwoWeeks))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@2.29.1/min/moment.min.js"></script>
```